# How to use Hive Set statement is SAS SQL?

Tags: hadoop, sas, impala

I am not aware of SAS SQL but one of our user is struggling with the syntax actually,

```
PROC SQL;
24         CONNECT TO IMPALA (USER="&TDUSER" PW="&***" DSN="BIGDATA" DATABASE= abc);
25         CREATE TABLE SIL_MONITORED AS SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO IMPALA
26         (
27         SELECT DISTINCT a.partyid, a.baselinerecordstatuscode, cast(b.cin as decimal(10)) as cin, a.business_date
28         /*cast(unix_timestamp(a.business_date, "yyyy-MM-dd") as timestamp) as business_date*/
29         FROM abc.baseline_party as a
30         LEFT JOIN
31         abc.baseline_relationship as b
32         on a.partyid = b.partyid
33         where a.business_date = (select max(business_date) from abc.baseline_party)
34         and upper(a.baselinerecordstatuscode) = 'MONITORED') ;
```

Recommendation from Bigdata side to use the below property to overcome the Scratch limit issue

> set mem_limit=1g

but we aren't sure to use it the above SAS Client side to incorporate and make it work. If it is Hue, it can be set at session level but not SAS.

He has tried like below but it was being ignored at Bigdata side for the other property **(SCRATCH_LIMIT)**,

```
PROC SQL;
24         CONNECT TO IMPALA (USER="&TDUSER" PW="&***" DSN="BIGDATAPROD" DATABASE= abc
24       **! conopts='SCRATCH_LIMIT=200g'**);
25         CREATE TABLE SIL_MONITORED AS SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO IMPALA
```

What's the right way to make

> set mem_limit=1g

to work with the above SQL from SAS side?

Thank you!

Comment: In your second connect attempt are those strange **! characters in the code? Or do they just appear in the SAS log (or perhaps an artifact of trying to copy from the SAS log into StackOverflow?)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by strange characters, these ones ** ** you meant? I just added here to make it bold.

Code : 

`PROC SQL;
24         CONNECT TO IMPALA (USER="&TDUSER" PW="&TDPW" DSN="BIGDATAPROD" DATABASE=abc
24       ! conopts='SCRATCH_LIMIT=200g');
25         CREATE TABLE SIL_MONITORED AS SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO IMPALA
26         (
27         SELECT DISTINCT a.partyid, a.baselinerecordstatuscode, cast(b.cin as decimal(10))`

Comment: Hi @Tom anything you'd like to add on top of this?

Comment: Does Impala provide any way for you to query the setting SCRATCH_LIMIT so you can test whether or not your attempt to change that setting via the connection options worked?

Comment: Got you, let me check whether it can be queried with SAS SQL to see if it returns the value and apply that way setting this limit, thanks!